# Jhipster/Spring Security that secured with OAuth2 (keycloak) Doesn't load role

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster, keycloak

Jhipster microservice application doesn't load role from keycloak server;

I try @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") and @Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"}), But my user hasn't this role, and I got error 403;

I checked SecurityUtils.isCurrentUserInRole but Authorities is empty too.

so how I could get and check user role in code?

ps: I started keycloak by docker and default setting for jhipster.

Comment: Have you checked in keycloak admin console?

Comment: May be related to https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9735 if you are using a version of JHipster less than v6.1.0